# Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function having following properties

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function defined by

$f(x)=\large \large \{x^{2/3}log x,x>0$

```
                  0 x=0
```

Then is uniformly continuous on [0,$\infty$)

f is definitely continuous at x=0 as $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}$f(x)=0

f is uniformly cont. iff $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}$f(x) and $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}$f(x) both exist.However not sure about the second limit .How to show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline:** Note that we have continuity on the closed interval $[0,1]$.

And on $[1,\infty)$ the derivative is bounded.

Comment: You are welcome.